# Keycloak realm probe is not getting ready

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to install keycloak on minikube using the below commands

```
minikube addons enable ingress

kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/latest/kubernetes-examples/keycloak.yaml
```

but my pod is not getting ready and throwing below error

```
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  5m1s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    5m                     kubelet            Pulling image "jboss/keycloak"
  Normal   Pulled     4m19s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "jboss/keycloak" in 41.257999512s
  Normal   Created    4m19s                  kubelet            Created container keycloak
  Normal   Started    4m18s                  kubelet            Started container keycloak
  Warning  Unhealthy  3m21s (x6 over 4m11s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.4:8080/auth/realms/master": dial tcp 172.17.0.4:8080: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  3m (x2 over 3m10s)     kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.4:8080/auth/realms/master": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Below are the logs of my pod

```
Added 'admin' to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json', restart server to load user
-b 0.0.0.0
=========================================================================

  Using Embedded H2 database

=========================================================================

=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/keycloak

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true   --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED

=========================================================================

←[0m14:59:58,215 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.10.2.Final
←[0m←[0m14:59:59,145 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final
←[0m←[0m14:59:59,161 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
←[0m←[0m14:59:59,435 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 12.0.1 (WildFly Core 13.0.3.Final) starting
←[0m←[0m14:59:59,659 INFO  [org.jboss.vfs] (MSC service thread 1-2) VFS000002: Failed to clean existing content for temp file provider of type temp. Enable DEBUG level log to find what caused this
←[0m←[0m15:00:01,069 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.13.1.Final
←[0m←[0m15:00:02,684 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
←[0m←[0m15:00:02,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,112 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,146 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.8.2.Final
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,165 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.2.Final
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,279 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYCONF0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile Config Subsystem
←[0m←[33m15:00:03,282 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,318 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYCLJG0001: Activating JGroups subsystem. JGroups version 4.2.5
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,328 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,333 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,348 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,370 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.13.2.Final
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,396 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Health Subsystem
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,411 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics Subsystem
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,411 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 2 IO threads with 16 max task threads based on your 1 available processors
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,429 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.19.Final
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
←[0m←[33m15:00:03,576 WARN  [org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCLWEBUT0007: No routing provider found for default-server; using legacy provider based on static configuration
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,664 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.2.2.Final starting
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,666 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final-redhat-00006
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.23.Final)
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,887 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/opt/jboss/keycloak/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
←[0m←[0m15:00:03,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,064 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 4 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,068 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,104 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,731 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,795 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,797 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,801 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow AJP listener ajp listening on 0.0.0.0:8009
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,835 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MODCLUSTER000001: Initializing mod_cluster version 1.4.1.Final
←[0m←[33m15:00:04,856 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,856 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MODCLUSTER000032: Listening to proxy advertisements on /224.0.1.105:23364
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,891 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,903 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name: "keycloak-server.war")
←[0m←[0m15:00:04,909 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
←[0m←[0m15:00:05,089 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8443
←[0m←[0m15:00:05,165 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
←[0m←[0m15:00:05,165 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
←[0m←[33m15:00:05,907 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000015: the send buffer of socket ManagedMulticastSocketBinding was set to 1.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
←[0m←[33m15:00:05,908 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket ManagedMulticastSocketBinding was set to 20.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
←[0m←[33m15:00:05,909 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000015: the send buffer of socket ManagedMulticastSocketBinding was set to 1.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
←[0m←[33m15:00:05,909 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket ManagedMulticastSocketBinding was set to 25.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
←[0m←[0m15:00:08,946 INFO  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x: no members discovered after 3026 ms: creating cluster as coordinator
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,072 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Corona Extra' 11.0.4.Final
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,109 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.jboss.JBossMarshaller'
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,168 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.marshalling.InfinispanProtoStreamMarshaller'
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,172 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.marshalling.InfinispanProtoStreamMarshaller'
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,172 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.jboss.JBossMarshaller'
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,178 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.marshalling.InfinispanProtoStreamMarshaller'
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,324 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel ejb
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,331 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel ejb
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,331 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel ejb
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,332 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel ejb
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,332 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel ejb
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,332 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x|0] (1) [keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x]
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,343 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x|0] (1) [keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x]
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,343 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x|0] (1) [keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x]
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,345 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x|0] (1) [keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x]
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,346 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x|0] (1) [keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x]
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,378 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) ISPN000079: Channel ejb local address is keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x, physical addresses are [172.17.0.4:55200]
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,384 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000079: Channel ejb local address is keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x, physical addresses are [172.17.0.4:55200]
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,385 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000079: Channel ejb local address is keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x, physical addresses are [172.17.0.4:55200]
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,386 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000079: Channel ejb local address is keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x, physical addresses are [172.17.0.4:55200]
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,386 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000079: Channel ejb local address is keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x, physical addresses are [172.17.0.4:55200]
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,459 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,464 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
←[0m←[0m15:00:10,873 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCLINF0002: Started http-remoting-connector cache from ejb container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,147 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYCLINF0002: Started work cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,214 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCLINF0002: Started loginFailures cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,219 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYCLINF0002: Started offlineSessions cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started authenticationSessions cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,224 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYCLINF0002: Started clientSessions cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,226 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYCLINF0002: Started sessions cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,243 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYCLINF0002: Started offlineClientSessions cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,250 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYCLINF0002: Started users cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYCLINF0002: Started realms cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,253 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCLINF0002: Started authorization cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,254 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYCLINF0002: Started keys cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:11,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYCLINF0002: Started actionTokens cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[33m15:00:11,438 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0273: Excluded subsystem webservices via jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not exist.
←[0m←[0m15:00:12,599 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) KC-SERVICES0001: Loading config from standalone.xml or domain.xml
←[0m←[0m15:00:13,190 INFO  [org.keycloak.url.DefaultHostnameProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) Frontend: <request>, Admin: <frontend>, Backend: <request>
←[0m←[33m15:00:13,388 WARN  [org.infinispan.encoding.impl.StorageConfigurationManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) ISPN000599: Configuration for cache 'realmRevisions' does not define the encoding for keys or values. If you use operations that require data conversion or queries, you should configure the cache with a specific MediaType for keys or values.
←[0m←[0m15:00:13,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYCLINF0002: Started realmRevisions cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[33m15:00:13,397 WARN  [org.infinispan.encoding.impl.StorageConfigurationManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) ISPN000599: Configuration for cache 'userRevisions' does not define the encoding for keys or values. If you use operations that require data conversion or queries, you should configure the cache with a specific MediaType for keys or values.
←[0m←[0m15:00:13,400 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYCLINF0002: Started userRevisions cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[33m15:00:13,401 WARN  [org.infinispan.encoding.impl.StorageConfigurationManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) ISPN000599: Configuration for cache 'authorizationRevisions' does not define the encoding for keys or values. If you use operations that require data conversion or queries, you should configure the cache with a specific MediaType for keys or values.
←[0m←[0m15:00:13,405 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYCLINF0002: Started authorizationRevisions cache from keycloak container
←[0m←[0m15:00:13,407 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) Node name: keycloak-866d6799c5-nks7x, Site name: null
←[0m←[0m15:00:14,305 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) Database info: {databaseUrl=jdbc:h2:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/keycloak, databaseUser=SA, databaseProduct=H2 1.4.197 (2018-03-18), databaseDriver=H2 JDBC Driver 1.4.197 (2018-03-18)}
←[0m←[0m15:00:18,825 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) Initializing database schema. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml
←[0m←[0m15:00:22,161 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: keycloak-default
        ...]
←[0m←[0m15:00:22,255 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.20.Final}
←[0m←[0m15:00:22,257 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
←[0m←[0m15:00:22,435 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.5.Final}
←[0m←[0m15:00:22,668 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
←[0m←[33m15:00:22,678 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
←[0m←[0m15:00:22,729 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) Envers integration enabled? : true
←[0m←[0m15:00:23,563 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.
←[0m←[0m15:00:23,646 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.21.Final
←[0m←[0m15:00:26,023 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
←[0m←[0m15:00:27,066 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) KC-SERVICES0050: Initializing master realm
←[0m←[0m15:00:28,460 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) KC-SERVICES0006: Importing users from '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,274 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) KC-SERVICES0009: Added user 'admin' to realm 'master'
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,352 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,356 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,358 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.ThemeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,363 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSecurityHeadersFilter from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,365 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.JsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,366 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.WelcomeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,366 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RobotsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,366 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminRoot from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,366 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002210: Adding provider singleton org.keycloak.services.util.ObjectMapperResolver from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,367 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RealmsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,560 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/auth' for server 'default-server'
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,831 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name : "keycloak-server.war")
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,948 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 12.0.1 (WildFly Core 13.0.3.Final) started in 32428ms - Started 687 of 972 services (687 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,956 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
←[0m←[0m15:00:29,956 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
←[0m←[0m15:00:31,082 INFO  [org.keycloak.keys.DefaultKeyManager] (default task-1) No keys found for realm=master and algorithm=RS256 for use=SIG. Generating keys.
←[0m←[0m15:00:31,086 INFO  [org.keycloak.keys.DefaultKeyManager] (default task-2) No keys found for realm=master and algorithm=RS256 for use=SIG. Generating keys.
```

I don't see any problem here but don't know why it's not working.. Any help or guidance would be helpful

FYI, Today I was able to create keycloak pods successfully once but for retesting it I have deleted minikube and then recreated it. Afterward again I ran the same commands but not able to bring pods back as I am getting above mentioned errors.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what happened is it shows Readiness Probe Failed but after some time Pod becomes ready automatically. Able to bring up the dashboard.